# raster2pgsql -C generates incorrect extent constraint

Tags: postgis, gdal, extents, rasterio, raster2pgsql

I am trying to load multiple rasters into the same table with the raster2pgsql. I verified via rasterio's `dataset.profile` that all of my rasters have the same bounds, centroid, and dimensions.

Using
`raster2pgsql -s 9822 -a -I -C -Y -f raster -n name -t 256x256 foo.tif public.raster_table`, most of the rasters load successfully, but some raise the following error

```
BEGIN 
ERROR: new row for relation "raster_table" violates check constraint "enforce_max_extent_raster"
```

I'm not sure why this is happening since all of the rasters have the same extent. I verified the constraint with `select ST_EXTENT(extent) from raster_columns where r_table_name='raster_table';` and noticed that the coordinates did not match what I was seeing with rasterio and gdalinfo.

Why is the extent of the raster tif file not being correctly translated to the extent constraint in postgis?

I'm expecting

```
BoundingBox(left=-2535863.8119731266, bottom=1419303.832999289, right=-1553663.8119731266, top=2544603.832999289)
```

but getting

```
BOX(-2228663.8119731266 1546203.832999289,-1844663.8119731266 2391003.832999289)
```

Comment: I'll also add that for some of the rasters, I seem to be writing more rows to the database. That seems unexpected for rasters with the same dimensions

Comment: Maybe some of the rasters seem to expand beyond some 256x256 tile boundary and therefore more tiles are generated. Just guessing, though.